# Running network.sh down on hyperledger fabric generates DOCKER_SOCK error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Everytime I run network.sh down, I always get a docker sock error on my MAC setup of hyperledger-Fabric.

```
[+] Running 8/8
 ⠿ Container cli                         Removed                                                                                                                                                                      10.2s
 ⠿ Container orderer.example.com         Removed                                                                                                                                                                       0.2s
 ⠿ Container peer0.org2.example.com      Removed                                                                                                                                                                       0.3s
 ⠿ Container peer0.org1.example.com      Removed                                                                                                                                                                       0.2s
 ⠿ Volume docker_peer0.org1.example.com  Removed                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 ⠿ Network fabric_test                   Removed                                                                                                                                                                       0.1s
 ⠿ Volume docker_peer0.org2.example.com  Removed                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 ⠿ Volume docker_orderer.example.com     Removed                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
WARN[0000] The "DOCKER_SOCK" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
1 error(s) decoding:

* error decoding 'Volumes[0]': invalid spec: :/host/var/run/docker.sock: empty section between colons
Removing remaining containers
Removing generated chaincode docker images
```

Is that a normal behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this issue by adding the following declaration code to the top of the network.sh file:

```
export DOCKER_SOCK="${DOCKER_HOST:-/var/run/docker.sock}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Johnny's answer did resolve the problem for me, but however when I run ./startFabric.sh, I have the error "Channel creation failed" (I believe this problem is associated to the DOCKER_SOCK's one). It's weird, yesterday i didn't have any kind of problem.

Comment: which flavor of Fabric are you running?  I would like to take a look on my end.  the declaration that I added only tells the application where to find the docker.sock file when it is running.  that is all.  It should not have any adverse effect elsewhere because once the terminal closes that declaration is no longer active or available from memory.

Comment: The latest. The problem is that since yesterday, whenever I try to run ./startFabric.sh, all docker containers (except for CA ones) are created but not running, so I have to force them to run from Docker Desktop. Obviously, this was the reason of my "channel creation failed" error. I still dont know why the containers don't start running automatically!  Before yesterday all worked perfectly, then these errors came together, that's why I thought they were correlated (but I could be wrong, I'm new in HLF).